# Python - reading hdf5 files in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython, hdf5

I have ~1000 separate HDF5 files stored on disk. Each only takes around 10ms to load into memory, so I was wondering what's the best way to load them parallely such that I get around a linear performance boost.

I've tried multiprocessing but that ends up being slower than just serially loading them in due to the overhead of setting up the processes. I've looked into Cython, specifically prange but having trouble optimizing it to get it faster. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think parallel processing will speed up your process, as it only speeds up computation time, not disk-access time. I would however suggest trying to gain performance by storing the files in a zipfile instead.

Comment: If all of the 10 ms are used reading from disk, what makes you think it is possible to speed up the process in the first place? if you are using 100 % of the bandwidth I guess there isn't anything that can be done, right?

Comment: isn't it possible to use Cython and release the GIL for multithreading? Couldn't that theoretically allow for parallel processing for IO bound tasks and increase performance?

Comment: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil - `h5py` manipulates Python objects, so cannot release the GIL.

Comment: @Michael Please post your PYX so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for mapreduce but if you only have one machine then I would recommend using pipes. Write one script to open the files and print the data to stdout, then in another script you read the data from stdin and process. The you redirect script1 into script2.

```
#  script1.py
FILES_TO_READ = ...
for filename in FILES_TO_READ:
  #  open the file
  #  do work
  #  print data

# script2.py
while True:
  line = input()
  #  do work

$> ./script1.py | ./script2.py
```